# How can I make a HTML select drop-down list close on blur?

Tags: html

Hi I need my drop down list boxes to close once they are out of focus or if the user is hovering over any other html element other than it. How can this be achieved?

I could think of a blur event, are there any better way to handle this?

Comment: Can you provide us your code?

Comment: Did you try anything before coming here?

Comment: It is just a try what I am trying to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good question**,  just this will work only in FF cause IE and Chrome do not recognize events targeting `option` elements :(

a way to (*not*) accomplish this is to set a `timeout` for the `option` elements that will trigger once we `mouseleave` it. If a new `mouseenter` is registered for another `option` in the tree, we simply clear the timeout that will otherwise `.blur()` **any** `select` on the page<sup>*</sup>.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ogItiXED/5/edit)**

```
var blurSelectTimeout;

function blurSelect(){
   blurSelectTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
       $('select').blur();
   },200);
}

$('select').mouseleave(blurSelect).find('option').hover(function(e){
  if(e.type=='mouseenter') clearTimeout(blurSelectTimeout);
  else blurSelect();
});
```

- Interestingly `$(this).parent('select').blur();` would not work, so this is my best try.

Comment: Could we determine the dimensions that the option elements cover and then use JS to close the drop-down when the mouse leaves its domain?

Comment: @deed02392 I thought about creating a way to detect `1.` The Select position in the viewport `2.` The number of `option` elements `3.` the possibility that the select opened downwards `4.` The mouse movement was after a click down (up respectively) `5.` the element `line-height` and therefore get the `hover` states intuitively. ... Too much work. Let the user simply click on the document to close this little fella until all browsers fix their bugs.

Comment: Indeed, thought it may be trivial but you're right, we should just be able to have event binding on option elements.

Comment: @deed yes we should be able to have **full control** over all and every element in the browser, if you ask me even over (also talking about design) prompts, alerts, scrollbars, and have a pretty fair unstyled (totally) HTML defaults. Strange how it was not immagined that way from the very beginning. Too many assumptions and browser bugs ruined hours of people's life-time.